# SQL Server : error for connection string

Tags: sql

My connection string

```
Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JMAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog=Goda;Integrated Security=True");
```

but I get an error:

> Unrecognized escape sequence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

This is Due to [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) in C#

Escape sequences are typically used to specify actions such as carriage returns and tab movements on terminals and printers.

Hence if you want to represent Backslash then you should use `\\`
or You can Use `@"....neglect...escape...sequence"`

```
Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JMAL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog=Goda;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: please add some explanation of your code showing how it solves the problem. This will help others who find this page after a search in the future

Comment: Can you explain this solution please

Comment: @jmalsalih  Now i provided more brief and MSDN Source

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is

```
Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=JMAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog=Goda;Integrated Security=True");
```